# key error when no dictionary is required

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function which sets the shutter on a camera and takes a float as input:

```
def changeShutter(value):
    global camera, shutter
    shutter['abs_value']+=value
    try:
        camera.set_property(**shutter)
    except:
        print "could not set shutter"
```

where `shutter` is a dictionary containing all the properties required for the shutter, and `abs_value` is the key whose value needs to be changed then set.

I can call this easily enough in a jupyter notebook I use for development with `changeShutter(0.05)` and it works just fine.

I then created a simple html button on a web page which sends a message to a flask-socket server containing the changeShutter function and, depending on the button pressed and the message therefore sent, it parses 0.05 or -0.05 like below:

```
@socketio.on('shutter request', namespace='/test')
def changeShutter(message):
    request = message['data']
    print 'Shutter request received: %s' %request
    if str(request) == "shutter increase":
        changeShutter(0.05)
    elif str(request) == "shutter decrease":
        changeShutter(-0.05)
```

I clearly receive one of the 2 possible options and correctly enter the correct `if` statement (I have tried debugging with extra print statements), but it throws a `key error: 0.05` at me for some reason.

When the function does not require a dictionary input, why do I get a key error?

Comment: why your flask function is named `changeShutter`? `changeShutter(0.05)` will end up calling `changeShutter(message)` and hence keyerror.

Comment: Perfect. Just noticed that and tried to submit the answer, only to find you had also found it. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Use namespacing. Don't use globals. Your coding style is the problem. What do you expect to happen when you define two functions with the exact same name?

Comment: Yep, that's the problem with writing the code in small snippets in 2 different editors - I just stupidly didn't realise I had given them the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this was a stupid error where I had 2 different functions of the same name.